# Is it necessary to use Timthumb in Wordpress 2.9+?

Tags: customization

as Wordpress 2.9 comes with built in post thumbnail features, is it necessary to use Timthumb ? if yes specify

Answer (score 2):

Was it ever necessary? Timthumb is not included in WordPress core.

You might be confusing it as WP feature because it is included in theme you use, but that is question to theme's developer and has little to do with WordPress itself.

Comment: I have happily never used timthumb.